# Alerts security Github - what is the correct way to fix vulnerability in yarn.lock/package-lock.json

Tags: security, github, npm, yarnpkg

As you know, Dependabot give us potential security vulnerability in a dependency in `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`.

Actually the problem is, there is no good for learning how to fix this.
If we search how, there is so many different way to do it, sometimes working, sometimes not. I'm find a lot of subject about this because a lot of people like me doesn't really understand how to fix vulnerability.

Did we have to replace by hand in all the file with correct version ?
For example `npm audit fix` upgrade package, sometimes not.
If we do `npm install packageName` the new package version appear but the old don't disappear, so the alert still here on gitHub.

And what about `yarn`?

In this Github project https://github.com/samuel3105/react-native-animated-tabBar, I have this:

[image]

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Did you find a recipe for yarn yet?

Comment: I usually upgrade my packages and the errors get dismissed

Answer (score 3):

Dependabot opened a pull request [Bump lodash from 4.17.15 to 4.17.19 #1](https://github.com/samuel3105/react-native-animated-tabBar/pull/1)

Normally upon a bug being discovered the package authors will fix it and release a new version. Dependabot is telling you bump your version to fix a potential vulnerability as the authors of lodash have released a fix. You can merge the pull request from dependabot and run `npm install` in all of your development environments.

Alternatively if a bleeding edge vulnerability is discovered, the maintainers of a package (lodash) have not yet released a patch (and you know a fix). You can use something like [patch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

"the new package version appear but the old don't disappear" was mentioned. If the version in the package.json corresponds to a patched working version and issues continue. Double check your node_modules folder it could still have the old version and not have updated. There may also be a *.lock file indicating a pinned version (we are using this version). Ensure that both of those resources are pointing to the up to date version of the package.

EDIT: I just peaked into the yarn.lock file of the linked repo and noticed the version `lodash "^4.17.13"`